# agenda en herencia

Tags: python

ENUNCIADO:
El siguiente ejercicio consiste en escribir un programa para gestionar una agenda telefónica con los nombres y los teléfonos de los conocidos de una persona. El programa incorporará las funciones para:
• Consultar el teléfono de una persona.
• Añadir el teléfono de una persona nueva.
• Eliminar el teléfono de una persona.
La agenda debe estar guardada en el fichero de texto agenda.txt donde el nombre de las personas y su teléfono deben aparecer separados por comas y cada persona debe aparecer en una línea distinta.
CODIGO:

```
import os

class Agenda():
      def __init__(self,persona,fichero):
          self.persona,self.fichero=persona,fichero
           
      def obtener_telefono(fichero,persona):
           try:
               f=open(fichero,'r')
           except FileNotFoundError    :
               return('¡El fichero' +fichero + 'no existe!\n')
           else:
               directorio =f.readlines()
               f.close()
               directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio
               ])
               if persona in directorio:
                   return directorio[persona]
               else:
                   return('¡La persona' +persona+ 'no existe\n')
                     
      def insertar_telefono(fichero,persona,telefono):
           try:
               f=open(fichero,'a')
           except FileNotFoundError:
               return('¡El fichero ' + fichero + 'no existe\n')
           else:
               f.write(persona+','+ telefono+'\n')    
               f.close()
               return ('El telefono se ha agregado.\n')
         
      def eliminar_telefono(fichero,persona):
           try:
               f=open(fichero,'r')
           except FileNotFoundError:
               return ('¡El fichero ' + fichero + 'no existe!\n')
           else:
               directorio =f.readlines()
               f.close()
               directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio])
               if persona in directorio:
                   del directorio[persona]
                   f=open(fichero,'w')
                   for nombre,telefono in directorio.items():
                       f.write(nombre + ',' + telefono)
                   f.close()
                   return ('La persona '+ persona + 'no existe\n')    
class Menu(Agenda):
   def __init__(self,persona,fichero,nombre,telefono,apellidos,email):
       super().__init__(persona,fichero)
       self.nombre,self.apellidos=nombre,apellidos
       self.telefono,self.email=telefono,email
   def directorio(self):
       fichero='agenda.txt'
       while True:
           opcion=Menu()
           if opcion=='1':
               nombre=input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
               print(self.obtener_telefono(fichero,nombre))
           elif opcion == '2':
               nombre=input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
               telefono=int(input('Introduzca el telefono de la persona:'))  
               print(self.insertar_telefono(fichero,nombre,telefono))
           elif opcion == '3':
               nombre=input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
               print(self.eliminar_telefono(fichero,nombre))
           elif opcion =='4':
               print(self.crear_directorio(fichero))  
           else:
               break
       return
   
   def crear_directorio(self,fichero):
     if os.path.isfile(self.fichero):
         pregunta=input('El fichero'+self.fichero+ 'ya existe.¿Desea borrarlo? (S/N)?')    
         if pregunta =='N':
             return 'No se ha añadido el fichero porque ya existe.\n'
         f=open(self.fichero,'w')
         f.close()
         return 'Se ha añadido el fichero.\n'  
   
   def crear_menu():
        print('Gestion de la agenda telefonica')
        print('*********************************')
        print('(1)-Obtener un telefono')
        print('(2)-Insertar un telefono')
        print('(3)-Eliminar un telefono')
        print('(4)-Crear la agenda telefonica')
        print('(0)-Salir')
        opcion=input('Seleccione la opcion elegida:')
        return opcion      
   crear_menu()
```

Me da este fallo,no se ejecuta correctamente:

Gestion de la agenda telefonica

---

(1)-Obtener un telefono
(2)-Insertar un telefono
(3)-Eliminar un telefono
(4)-Crear la agenda telefonica
(0)-Salir
Seleccione la opcion elegida:2
PS C:\Users\seten\PYTHON

Como podrás ver no sale la opción Insertar un teléfono ni ningún otra opción.
Lo mismo al hacer este ejercicio mediante herencia lo complico aun mas,y debería hacerlo solo con funciones ,pero quería hacerlo elegante el ejercicio

Ahora me da este error en el código:
ahora me da este error en el método obtener_telefono:

```
def obtener_telefono(self,fichero,persona):
            try:
                f=open(fichero,'r')
            except FileNotFoundError    :
                return('¡El fichero' +fichero + 'no existe!\n')
            else:
                directorio =f.readlines()
                f.close()
                directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio])
                if persona in directorio:
                    return directorio[persona]
                else:
                    return('¡La persona' +persona+ 'no existe\n')
Error:

Gestion de la agenda telefonica  
*********************************
(1)-Obtener un telefono
(2)-Insertar un telefono
(3)-Eliminar un telefono
(4)-Crear la agenda telefonica
(0)-Salir
Seleccione la opcion elegida:1
Introduzca el nombre de la persona:paco
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 96, in <module>
    menu.directorio()
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 60, in directorio
    print(self.obtener_telefono(fichero,nombre))
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 17, in obtener_telefono
    directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

---

ahora me da este error en el método obtener_telefono:

```
def obtener_telefono(self,fichero,persona):
            try:
                f=open(fichero,'r')
            except FileNotFoundError    :
                return('¡El fichero' +fichero + 'no existe!\n')
            else:
                directorio =f.readlines()
                f.close()
                directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio])
                if persona in directorio:
                    return directorio[persona]
                else:
                    return('¡La persona' +persona+ 'no existe\n')
```

Error:

```
Gestion de la agenda telefonica  
*********************************
(1)-Obtener un telefono
(2)-Insertar un telefono
(3)-Eliminar un telefono
(4)-Crear la agenda telefonica
(0)-Salir
Seleccione la opcion elegida:1
Introduzca el nombre de la persona:paco
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 96, in <module>
    menu.directorio()
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 60, in directorio
    print(self.obtener_telefono(fichero,nombre))
  File "d:\seten\PYTHON\Herencia.py", line 17, in obtener_telefono
    directorio=dict([tuple(line.split(','))for line in directorio])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

Comment: El primer parámetro de un método es siempre `self`. Eso te falta en varias partes.

Comment: `fichero` es un argumento dado al crear un objeto `Agenda`. Los métodos de `Agenda` no deben recibir `fichero`, sino usar `self.fichero`.

Comment: no había dado cuenta del parámetro self,pero de todas formas sigue persistiendo el mismo fallo. Un saludo cordial,

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimado Paco Ventura.
Revisando tu codigo pude identificar algunos errores, los cuales enumero a continuacion:

No defines el parametro self en algunos de los métodos.

En la función `directorio` de la clase `Menu` esta declarando el nombre del fichero, pero ese nombre ya lo defines al instanciar a la clase Menu con los argumentos iniciales

```
fichero = self.fichero
```

en lugar de

```
fichero = "agenda.txt"
```

En la funcion `directorio` de la clase `Menu` debes modificar los siguiente:

```
opcion = self.crear_menu()
```

en lugar de

```
opcion = Menu()
```

A continuación te dejo el código con las modificaciones

---

```
import os


class Agenda():
    def __init__(self, persona, fichero):
        self.persona, self.fichero = persona, fichero

    def obtener_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
        try:
            f = open(fichero, 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return ('¡El fichero' + fichero + 'no existe!\n')
        else:
            directorio = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            directorio = dict([tuple(line.split(',')) for line in directorio])
            if persona in directorio:
                return directorio[persona]
            else:
                return ('¡La persona' + persona + 'no existe\n')

    def insertar_telefono(self, fichero, persona, telefono):
        try:
            f = open(fichero, 'a')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return ('¡El fichero ' + fichero + 'no existe\n')
        else:
            f.write(persona + ',' + str(telefono) + '\n')
            f.close()
            return ('El telefono se ha agregado.\n')

    def eliminar_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
        try:
            f = open(fichero, 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return ('¡El fichero ' + fichero + 'no existe!\n')
        else:
            directorio = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            directorio = dict([tuple(line.split(',')) for line in directorio])
            if persona in directorio:
                del directorio[persona]
                f = open(fichero, 'w')
                for nombre, telefono in directorio.items():
                    f.write(nombre + ',' + telefono)
                f.close()
                return ('La persona ' + persona + 'no existe\n')


class Menu(Agenda):
    def __init__(self, persona, fichero, nombre, telefono, apellidos, email):
        super().__init__(persona, fichero)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellidos = apellidos
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.email = email

    def directorio(self):
        fichero = self.fichero
        while True:
            opcion = self.crear_menu()
            if opcion == '1':
                nombre = input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
                print(self.obtener_telefono(fichero, nombre))
            elif opcion == '2':
                nombre = input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
                telefono = int(input('Introduzca el telefono de la persona:'))
                print(self.insertar_telefono(fichero, nombre, telefono))
            elif opcion == '3':
                nombre = input('Introduzca el nombre de la persona:')
                print(self.eliminar_telefono(fichero, nombre))
            elif opcion == '4':
                print(self.crear_directorio(fichero))
            else:
                break
        return

    def crear_directorio(self, fichero):
        if os.path.isfile(self.fichero):
            pregunta = input('El fichero' + self.fichero + 'ya existe.¿Desea borrarlo? (S/N)?')
            if pregunta == 'N':
                return 'No se ha añadido el fichero porque ya existe.\n'
            return
        f = open(self.fichero, 'w+')
        f.close()
        return 'Se ha añadido el fichero.\n'

    def crear_menu(self):
        print('Gestion de la agenda telefonica')
        print('*********************************')
        print('(1)-Obtener un telefono')
        print('(2)-Insertar un telefono')
        print('(3)-Eliminar un telefono')
        print('(4)-Crear la agenda telefonica')
        print('(0)-Salir')
        opcion = input('Seleccione la opcion elegida:')
        return opcion


menu = Menu("Ramon Mendez", "agenda.txt", "Ramon", "50762658585", "Mendez", "ramon@mendez.com")
menu.directorio()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias GmrYael,lo del parámetro self me había dado cuenta que faltaba en varias partes del codigo,que posteriormente corregi pero no sabia que el fallo estaba en el método directorio.Tengo que repasar la POO.